# User determined CSS and paths in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am building a Rails 3.2 app which has some functionality where a user can apply different themes (i.e. CSS files) to their websites.  I have a Theme model with a theme name and a file name - pretty straightforward.

My question is, where should these css files sit?  Should they be in the /assets folder, or in the /public folder?  They can't be added to the pipeline as far as I know as I don't know which css file the user will choose so can't precompile.

If I use something like:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "plain.css"
```

It of course generates a path to /assets/plain.css which is not a valid path.

I can put it in /public and generate the path using something like 
`"public/themes/" + theme.file`

But something about that feels wrong.  Any architecture suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all themes are simple pre–existing stylesheets of which the user picks one, I’d go with

```
/app/assets/stylesheets/themes/plain.css
```

Then use this in the view:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "themes/plain"

# or e.g. using the model

stylesheet_link_tag "themes/#{current_user.theme.file_name}“
```

You could also consider creating a `theme_stylesheet_tag` helper which does this for you in a more cleanly way.

Comment: thanks, but this does not seem to work.  I get the following error when trying to access this path: 'No route matches [GET] "/app/assets/stylesheets/themes/green.css'

Comment: Sounds like you’re using the whole path for the link tag. Make sure you’re calling `stylesheet_link_tag "themes/green"` but *are placing the file in* `/app/assets/stylesheets/themes/green.css`.

Comment: Thanks - looks like the problem was that `current_user.theme.file_name` was stored with the `.css` extension.  `stylesheet_link_tag` does need (accept?) this.

Comment: Hmm - scratch that - it doesn't seem to matter if the .css extension is there or not stylesheet_link_tag can handle it - I must have been doing something else wrong.  Either way it works now so thank you!